# Spring Security - All JQuery Ajax post requests return 404

Tags: jquery, ajax, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

All my `$.ajax`, both `POST` and `GET` were working fine, but as soon as I integrated `Spring security 3.2.6` into my project the `POST` ajax requests stopped working without loggin any issues.

### spring-security.xml

```
<beans:beans xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.2.xsd">

    <!--Permit all Web resources to bypass proxy-->
    <http pattern="/js/**" security="none"/>
    <http pattern="/css/**" security="none"/>
    <http pattern="/fonts/**" security="none"/>
    <http pattern="/images/**" security="none"/>

    <http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true" >

        <intercept-url pattern="/login" access="isAnonymous()"/>

        <intercept-url pattern="/workflow**" access="hasRole('ROLE_WORKFLOW_ADMIN')"/>
        <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="hasAnyRole('ROLE_ADMIN','ROLE_WORKFLOW_ADMIN','ROLE_DMS_ADMIN')"/>

        <access-denied-handler error-page="/403"/>

        <form-login
                login-page="/login"
                default-target-url="/dashboard"
                authentication-failure-url="/login?error"
                username-parameter="username"
                password-parameter="password"/>

        <logout invalidate-session="true" logout-success-url="/login?logout"/>

        <csrf/>
    </http>

    <!-- Select users and user_roles from database -->
    <authentication-manager>
        <authentication-provider ref="daoAuthenticationProvider"/>
    </authentication-manager>

    <beans:bean id="daoAuthenticationProvider"
                class="org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider">
        <beans:property name="userDetailsService" ref="authService"/>
    </beans:bean>


</beans:beans>
```

### Web.xml

```
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
          http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
         version="2.5">

    <filter>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>
            /WEB-INF/mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml
            /WEB-INF/spring-security.xml
        </param-value>
    </context-param>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <error-page>
        <exception-type>java.lang.Throwable</exception-type>
        <location>/error</location>
    </error-page>
    <error-page>
        <error-code>500</error-code>
        <location>/error</location>
    </error-page>

</web-app>
```

Edit

---

The URL I am trying to access is

> http://localhost:8080/ADMIN/workflow/sample-ajax

Could it be something to with spring security ?

Comment: Please share the URL that you are hitting from the ajax request.

Comment: _POST ajax requests stopped_...not a demonstrative problem statement. But are there in error in the console. it could be possible your url might have changed a little.

Comment: @Mithun - See my Edit above

Comment: Based on the configuration, URL's matching `/workflow**` should have `ROLE_WORKFLOW_ADMIN` role. Could you please confirm if the user that you are using belongs to this role?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Finally after three agonizing days, I found the problem and boy was it stupid.

The problem was that I have enabled `csrf` protection in spring security. And that was causing my post requests to be forbidden which triggers the `access-denied-handler` error page, since I have not mapped my `access-denied-handler`to the `"/403"` error page as shown below, my `http 403/401` was being masked by the `http 404`

```
<access-denied-handler error-page="/403"/>
```

So in Short

1. Map your `access-denied-handler` error page to a valid url
2. If you use csrf protection, then always make sure that you pass them in the ajax post request as such

> $.ajax({method :'POST', url : '/ajax',data :
>   {"${_csrf.parameterName}" : "${_csrf.token}"}});

Answer (score 5):

There is one more situation that must be consulted specially when you are implementing spring security 4, one needs form button (not "a href").

https://spring.io/blog/2013/08/21/spring-security-3-2-0-rc1-highlights-csrf-protection/#ajax-requests.

A> form post request sent: input type hidden in **both** login/logout buttons

```
<input type="hidden" name="${_csrf.parameterName}" value="${_csrf.token}"/>
```

B> For AJAX post request add following in your JSP page after taglib declarations.

```
<meta name="_csrf" content="${_csrf.token}" />
<meta name="_csrf_header" content="${_csrf.headerName}" />
```

and some where above closing **body** tag in jsp any where as it "on ready"

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    var token = $("meta[name='_csrf']").attr("content");
    var header = $("meta[name='_csrf_header']").attr("content");
    $(document).ajaxSend(function(e, xhr, options) {
        xhr.setRequestHeader(header, token);
    });
});
 </script>
```

It should work!
if you have CORS issues still remaining, see article below.
http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/cors/

Answer (score 1):

### Alternative solution using Spring Boot 2.2.1 with Spring MVC, Spring Security 5 and Thymeleaf 3.0.11

I am so happy that I finally found a solution to this problem, that I would also like to share it here:

### **Problem**:

In my case, it was a $.ajax POST request to a valid URL returning 404 error status (not found).

@Mushtaq Jameel has explained that the original cause of the problem is **csrf**, which is **enabled by default as of Spring Security 4** ([source](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-csrf)).

### **Solution**:

I have not tested what @Mushtaq Jameel proposed, but this elegant quick fix worked for me:

AJAX code:

```
  $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "/",
                data: $('.cd-signin-modal__form.sign-up').serialize(),  // <- FIX    
                success: // some code
                error: // some code
            });

        }
```

In other words, the solution is calling the .serialize() method on the HTML form itself.

What happens then, is that a **_csfr token is automatically added** in the POST request as an additional form parameter:

[image]

This is again due to csrf being enabled by default in the newer versions of Spring Security ([here](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-csrf) it is mentioned that this hidden form parameter is added automatically).

My Spring MVC controller then accepts the form like this:

```
 @PostMapping("/")
    public String createUser(@Valid @ModelAttribute User user, @Valid @ModelAttribute UserDetails userDetails, BindingResult errors) {
        if (errors.hasErrors()) {
            // handle errors
        }
        //  persist objects in database
        return "index";
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to post using normal http request for using spring security you have to use particular  set of variable name you can google it .

Also check if we can send post request to restricted URL using AJAX.

Comment: @himashu - I did it works just fine also the GET requests don't seem to be having a problem with the ajax call. What do you mean by particular set of variable name, are you talking about j_username & j_password, aren't those things for login ?